# Correct usage of the LaTeX \newcounter and associated commands?

Tags: macros, counters

Previously I had a question about the \newcount command. I was then led to consider the \newcounter command instead, that does allow the use of digits in counter names. Accordingly, I have modified the MWE I submitted with the previous question. My present question is wheter the usage exemplified in the attached MWE is in accordance with correct, or recommended usage within the LaTeX framework ?    Here is the MWE :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Example LaTeX-file that illustrates the use     %%
%%  of \newcounter and associated commands          %%
%%                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%         

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=0.75in, paperheight=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{a}  \newcounter{b} \newcounter{c7}

\setcounter{a}{1}   \setcounter{b}{41} \setcounter{c7}{78}

\noindent
a = \number\value{a} 
\par \vskip 5pt \noindent
b = \number\value{b}  
\par \vskip 5pt \noindent 
c7 = \number\value{c7} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is sort of legal latex but clearly not "good latex style". `\noindent` shouldn't normaly be used, and `\vskip` shouldn't be used. (`\vspace`) Normally within a document one would use a blank line rather than `\par` (`\par` is more use within macro definitions where a blank line often looks less convenient, as you may wish to indent code).

LaTeX counters like `a` have a print representation command `\thea` which should be used to print the value. The document sets this up so that if the value is `2` it may print as **2** or **3.1.2** or **a** or **ii** depending on the style specified.  `\value{a}` returns the underlying number in the register. `\number\value{a}` prints the decimal value of that value but is almost never used.

Note also that `c7` while a latex counter in some sense is inconvenient as the print command `thec7` is not accessible as `\thec7`  so you would have to use `\csname thec7\endcsname` but really there is no advantage in using non-letters in the counter name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  In TeX I have no one looking over my shoulder, it is only the printout or pdf that counts. But usually I put \parindent=0pt at the very beginning, and then I make indents with \quad, or some macro of variable size. Then I get the page to look like I want it. In LaTeX I noted the irritating indents, and the \noindent command is the only way I know of, how to avoid it.

Comment: @user35145 - In the absence of specific examples of "irritating indents", it's not really possible to give advice on how to proceed without doing a lot of visual formatting (which is, it would appear, the method you're familiar with).

Comment: @user35145 well the only content of your question was did your example code show recommended usage and the answer to that is fairly clearly "no". Of course it's a free world and not following recommended usage isn't necessarily evil:-)  (but if you get in the habit of filling your documents with `\quad` and `\noindent` etc, then if you ever do need to submit an article to a journal, you will probably find they reject the manuscript and re-key it as explicit spacing makes their life a pain as latex documents are supposed to reflow to different page sizes and fonts according to publisher needs.

Comment: @user35145 -- Why would you set `\parindent` to 0 and then manually indent paragraphs?  Why not just set `\parindent` to the desired value and be done with it? (And why would you want indents of "variable size"?!)

Comment: @jon There has to be a harmony to the page. And therefore adjustments are needed. To replace \quad I used for example \def\ss3{\hskip 1cm\relax}, and then I use that value throughout. But if I am not satisfied, I can change it to \def\ss3{\hskip 1.2cm\relax}. I feel I have more control then. But of course David has a good point. And I am grateful for his good advice. But how do I turn off the indent in LaTex? ;-)

Comment: @user35145 `\def\ss3` defines the command `\ss` (which is the German s-z ligature) so that it has to be followed by a 3 and then adds a space. Do you really intend that?

Comment: If you must, you can do `\usepackage{parskip}` to eliminate paragraph indentation and insert some vertical space instead. Or you could just do `\setlength{\parinent}{1.5em}` or whatever in your preamble. You really don't want variable indentation within the document, so setting it once in the preamble makes sense and will be much less irritating if you or an editor later needs to format your document to fit a publishing template.

Comment: @David I just tested it in LaTeX, and it worked, even without a space. The name is totally arbitrary, but maybe it was an abbreviation for "space skip no.3". I would also have ss1, ss2, etc. I can then fine tune spaces by fractions of millimeters to avoid black boxes in the right margin. BTW your very fine idea "\thea" did not work for the counter named "c7". I tried different combinations and arrived at \the\value{c7}. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: @user35145 `\def\ss1{.}` \def\ss2{..}` all (re)define the same command, `\ss` so I don't know what you mean by "I would also have ss1, ss2, etc." and I explicitly mentioned  `\thec7` does not work in my answer, so you should use counter names using letters.

Comment: @user35145 Perhaps you would really be more comfortable using TeX and avoiding LaTeX? It seems that you explicitly do not want to use the kind of markup which LaTeX is designed to support, so you are fighting its very raison d'être. But there is nothing which says you must use LaTeX if you don't like it ;).

Comment: @David  The reason for wanting to use numerical indices, was because I wanted to try to do mathematics, matrix multiplication, power series and things like that.  I can of course also use letters, once I am aware of the difficulties with digits in names, e.g. "ae" stands for 15. You are right about \ss2 and \ss3 not working well together. I must have used some other way such \ssa and \ssb then. The names are more or less arbitrary, but should be chosen easy to recall. What it means is that I write my own (simple) macros, that differ from document to document.

Comment: @user35145 the site isn't really set up for discussion (it will start giving automated complaints about the length of this thread soon) but apart from naming issues, if you are adding explicit spacing routinely into your document then something is very wrong. without seeing an example (in another question) I can't really say more than that.

Comment: I tried to model my pages after a book I really liked, that was printed 150 years ago. But following TeX slavishly invariably gave a totally different "look". Therefore a lot of adjustments needed to be made. PostScript might have been a much better choice, but much more laborious, I am afraid. For "normal" work I usually do not worry too much.  But "looks" IS important. Donald Knuth thinks so too.

Comment: @user35145 look is important but also how you use markup to achieve that look. Using latex correctly doesn't mean accepting lower quality output.

Comment: @user35145 -- What I was indirectly suggesting was, as cfr explained, you can simply redefine the value `\parindent` to whatever value you want so each paragraph starts with the "correct" indent.  If you want to change it locally for a special situation, you can do it inside a group (`\begingroup\setlength{\parindent}{<new local value>} ... \endgroup`).  Having to put an `\ssa` or `\ssb` at the start of every paragraph makes global control of your document *harder*, not easier.  This is (part of) what David is suggesting about 'how you use markup'.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have always done in TeX, putting \parindent=30pt (e.g.) at the very beginning. But when I came to LaTeX that particular command didn't work any longer. And so I took recourse to \noindent. But it had to be repeated for every skip. But now I think I've been given a lot of nice tips, and learned a lot. Thanks!  PS what reference book would you suggest? French or German is fine.

Comment: @user35145 `\setlength\parindent{30pt}` should work, if it is not working then probably you have some markup that is defeating that, but impossible to guess what you have done without any example. (and it's off topic for this question which is notionally about counters)